# Invertibility of a matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have to study the invertibility of this matrix
$$A(k)=\bigg[\bigg(\alpha_j-\frac{ik}{4\pi}\bigg)\delta_{jj'}-\tilde{f}(y_j-y_{j'})\bigg]_{jj'}$$
where
$\tilde{f}(x)$ is $\tilde{f}(x)=\frac{e^{ik|x|}}{4\pi|x|}$ se $x\neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise in the two cases 
$\Im k>0$, $\Im k=0$
but i don't succed in this purpose.

Comment: So is $k$ purely imaginary or simply Im $k>0$?

Comment: In the definition is $\Im k>0$; in the proof he chosses it purely immaginary! So I don't understand

Comment: Everywhere I see $k$ it is multiplied by $i$ so I suspect you mean that $k$ is real and positive. Otherwise there are many $i$'s here and there ($k,ik,i\lambda=k\ldots$) Also I think you might want to change the title "Invertibility of a matrix--relationship between derivative and eigenvalues?" just so that it is more descriptive.

Comment: What do you know about the $\alpha_j$'s?

Comment: They are costants in $\mathbb{R}$.